# Return data type of the function in c programming

Tags: c, function, return-type, exitstatus

i have to use ***exit(1)*** command in a function.
Does it have anything to do with the return data type of the function in which it is being used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.  The `exit` function never returns but instead terminates the process it's called from.  The C compiler has no intuitive understanding of it and treats it like any other `void` returning function.

This does mean though that while `exit` will end your function the C compiler doesn't see it that way.  Hence it will still want a valid return else it will spit out warnings /errors (with a high enough error level enabled).  But this is easy enough to work around

```
int myFunc() {
  ...
  exit(exitCode);
  return 42;  // Never hit but keeps C compiler happy
}
```

Comment: +1 for returning 42. I'd give another +1 for the good answer however it's not possible.

Comment: Correct.  But note that the argument to `exit()` is used as the exit status for your program -- and the meaning of that status code is system-specific.  On Unix-like systems, `exit(1);` denotes failure; on VMS, it denotes success.  Use `exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);` for success, `exit(EXIT_FAILURE);` for failure (declared in `<stdlib.h>`, which you should be `#include`ing anyway if you're calling `exit()`).  (As a special case, `exit(0);` always indicates success.)  `exit(N);` is equivalent to `return N;` in `main()`.